# Comparison operator != not working in <select> field

Tags: php, html

Please i want to ensure only male or female is selected in the dropdown if not fail the form but my validation keeps returning false even if male or female is selected.

Html

```html
<select name="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Nonesense" selected>Nonesense</option>
</select>
```

Here is the php code

```php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['gender'] != 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] != 'Female' ) { 
        echo 'sorry it must be either male or female'; return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your if statements were all smushed on to the one line for some reason, I've fixed that by reformatting the code so it's easier to read and understand. Also keep in mind your gender selection control may not pass legal muster in some legal jurisdictions, I recommend consulting legal advice. Some jurisdictions might offer a neutral gender, some may require that the user can opt out of identifying their gender. Some user might also consider `nonesense` offensive

Comment: Thanks @tom i will replace the nonsense in my main project code, but then i know dkeeling method works atleast i can get the project running but then for a programmer i need to know why using != or !in_array() or anything ! Seems not to work with <select>

Comment: The `select` is irrelevant, once the value is submitted via `POST` there's no way to know how or where the value came from, just that it's a value with a name submitted via `POST`. A bit like when you buy lego, you don't know if the lego was made in a mould,  assembled by hand,  or  chisselled from a larger piece of plastic, and it  doesn't matter..  If the answer from dkeeling answers your question you should mark it as the  accepted answer, otherwise  leave comments on that answer

Comment: On closer inspection, this question has nothing to do with WordPress, it's a generic pure PHP question that just  happens to be on a  WordPress site. You should have asked it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is due to a logic error, which becomes obvious if you follow the code manually for each value It has nothing to do with the `select` element, or special behaviour of `!` or `!=`

So lets look at your conditional:

```
$_POST['gender'] != 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] != 'Female'
```

- if ( gender is not male ) OR ( gender is not female )

  - then complain it must be male/female

So lets say that the gender is male:

- if ( false ) OR ( true )

  - then complain it must be male/female

Since true is true, it resolves to `if true` and the complaint appears.

So it appears, the problem is a misunderstanding of how `OR` works

`a OR b` <- this resolve to true if either 'a', 'b', or both a and b are true.

What I think you meant was:

`if ( gender is male OR gender is female ) is not true`

rather than

`if ( gender is not male ) OR ( gender is not female )`

**But finally, this question and answer has nothing to do with WordPress.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your "or" operator.  For example, even though "Male" may be selected, "Female" is not, which still makes the statement true as a whole.

I would do something like this:

```
$accepted_values = array('Male', 'Female');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(in_array($_POST['gender'],$accepted_values)) {
    // Value is 'Male' or 'Female'
  } else {
    echo 'sorry it must be either male or female';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dkeeling but i equally used in_array() but is not working, the problem is not from the OR because it can only be a problem if i use &&  so the problem is not OR, the whole issue is this symbol ! Which is used to turn a statement to false, it seems not to be working and thats what i want to find out why

Comment: If you use $_POST['gender'] == 'Female' || $_POST ['gender'] == 'Male' everything works fine but it means validation will fail if any of them is selected but will pass validation if none of neither Male or Female is selected, so the huge problem is !     Even if i use !in_array() which means not in array i will face the same issue